# Why is my classes method giving an error when it just calls and checks a method that works perfectly fine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, logic

Given a square that is an object defined with a center at a certain point, and an edge length, the contains_square method is supposed to return True when a square is contained within a circle, and False when it is not. I began by defining a method that can successfully tell whether or not a certain point is contained within a circle with a given center and radius. To find if the circle contains the square, the contains_square method checks if the corners are within the circle with the contains_point method. If they are contained within the circle, it should return true. However when given a circle object defined with a center of (1, 2) and radius of 4 as c = Circle((1, 2), 4)  and two squares defined the same way as s1 = Square((2, 2), 1) and s2 = Square((3, 2), 6) it correctly returns true for the first one but incorrectly returns True for the second one.

Here is the code

```
import math

class Circle(object):
    def __init__(self, center, radius):
        self.center = center
        self.radius = radius

    def get_center(self):
        return self.center

    def get_radius(self):
        return self.radius

    def contains_point(self, p):
        n1 = p[0] - self.center[0]
        n2 = p[1] - self.center[1]

        distance = n1 + n2
        if distance <= (self.radius * self.radius):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def contains_square(self, s):
        ur = s.ur
        ul = s.ul
        lr = s.lr
        ll = s.ll

        if self.contains_point(ur) and self.contains_point(ul) and self.contains_point(lr) and self.contains_point(ll):
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def contains(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, tuple):
            self.contains_point(x)
        elif isinstance(x, Square):
            self.contains_square(x)
        else:
            cen1 = self.center
            cen2 = x.get_center()

            n1 = cen2[0] - cen1[0]
            n2 = cen2[1] - cen1[1]
            distance = math.sqrt(n1 + n2)
            total = distance + x.get_radius()

            if total < self.radius:
                return True
            else:
                return False
```

I tried many approaches such as extending the check to all four corners, having the corners defined as separate variables (which are the ur, ul, lr, and ll variables calling the squares method), and using nested if statements instead of and statements. I am not sure what part is incorrect and where the incorrect return is coming from. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `contains_point` distance should be calculated as `distance = math.sqrt(n1**2 + n2**2)`. Your formula is wrong.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question can be significantly improved, which in turn vastly improves the chances of getting an answer. At the minimum, if there is an error message, include the error message (along with the stacktrace). For bonus points, try to make a [example]. Your code is not reproducible, as we can't be sure which function you were calling, and with which parameters. It is not minimal, as there is a lot of code that is not relevant. EDIT: And if there is no error message, then stating "giving an error" instead of "producing wrong results" is misleading.

Comment: Note that `if cond: return True; else: return False` is the same as `return cond`

Answer (score 1):

You are using wrong distance metric. What you actually calculate in `contains_point` resembles Manhattan distance, but you need Euclidean distance in order to calculate it correctly:

```py
def distance(point_a, point_b):
    return math.sqrt(sum([(p - q)**2 for p, q in zip(point_a, point_b)]))
```

But in fact, you don't have to bother with that because there is already built-in function for that: `math.dist`
With that, the `contains_point` method could look like this:

```py
def contains_point(self, p):
    return math.dist(p, self.center) <= self.radius
```

You can improve other things as well. I give you a hint to improve the method `contains_square`: you don't have to check all 4 corners if you get the smallest circle that still contains the square and check if this circle fits into the other one.

Comment: Manhattan distance would be `abs(n1) + abs(n2)`.

Comment: Yes, you are right.